# After installing tinymce.mvc.jquery my application started throwing a System.MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

the asp.net mvc 4 application that I have being working and was responding fine started throwing exception after I installed **Tinymce.Mvc.Jquery**. Here is the exception together with its stack trace

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.<.cctor>b__0()' to access security
>   critical method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.WebPagesDeployment.IsExplicitlyDisabled(System.String)'
>   failed

```
[MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.<.cctor>b__0()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.WebPagesDeployment.IsExplicitlyDisabled(System.String)' failed.]
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.<.cctor>b__0() +32
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +319
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +126
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +53
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.get_IsExplicitlyDisabled() +79
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +98
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +157
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

and  here is my config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
      <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />

      <!--Note: I added this configuration. It was gotten from the nop commerce source code. -->
      <section name="BestConfig" type="Best.Core.Configuration.BestConfig, Best.Core" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>

    <!--Note: I added this configuration. It was gotten from the nop commerce source code. -->
    <BestConfig>
        <DynamicDiscovery Enabled="true" />
        <Startup IgnoreStartupTasks="true" />
        <Engine Type="" />
        <Themes basePath="~/Content/" />
    </BestConfig>

     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BestDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=CIZA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BestDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <!-- <add name="BestDb" connectionString="Data Source=CIZA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SteekerDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> -->
    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="MvcMailer.BaseURL" value="" />
    </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

      <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
          </providers>
      </membership>

      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
          <providers>
              <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
          </providers>
      </roleManager>


      <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
      </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="routes.axd" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
    <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" /></httpHandlers>
  <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> --><httpModules>
            <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
        <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" /></httpModules></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="AttributeRouting" path="routes.axd" verb="*" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
    <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" /></handlers>
  <modules>
            <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" /></modules></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
      <!-- If you are having issues with Glimpse, please include this. It will help us figure out whats going on. 
      <logging level="Trace" />-->

      <!-- Want to use Glimpse on a remote server? Ignore the LocalPolicy by removing this comment.
      <runtimePolicies>
        <ignoredTypes>
          <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
        </ignoredTypes>
      </runtimePolicies>-->
    </glimpse><resizer>
    <plugins>
    <add name="DiskCache" />
    <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
    </plugins>
    </resizer>
    <system.net>


        <mailSettings>
            <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials 
            <smtp from="Steekerz@gmail.com">
                <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="some-email@gmail.com" password="valid-password" />
            </smtp> -->

            <!-- Method#2: Dump emails to a local directory -->
            <!---->
            <smtp from="Steekerz@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                <network host="localhost" />
                <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\CIZA\Documents\Emails" />
            </smtp>

        </mailSettings>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
        <settings>
            <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
            <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
        </settings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

please any help on this will be greatly appreciated as it is causing me to lose sleep as the project is already running late. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Web.config's assembly binding redirect section, you are mixing System.Web.WebPages v2 with a bunch of other related assemblies' (System.Web.Razor, System.Web.WebPages.Deployment) v3.  Make sure that these are all unified.

Edit: The easiest course of action would probably be to upgrade the project to MVC 5.  This will unify on System.Web.WebPages v3 throughout your project, then you can pull in components like tinymce.mvc.jquery which have v3 dependencies.